# How would a futuristic robot soldier look like?

Tags: warfare, hard-science, near-future, robots, armors

I feel that whenever I search for something like “futuristic robot soldier”, the results are always similar and they look like designs and concepts made by ARTISTS, not ENGINEERS. As far as I know, the only exception is Boston Dynamics’ Atlas. It lacks head and the legs are shorter than human legs, which is reasonable. But that’s it. It seems to me that pretty much anywhere else robot soldiers are depicted as basically same humans, but made of metal and with more rectangular limbs. I wonder, how would a combat Atlas look like?

My main questions are:

1. Will it be shorter than human to be harder to hit or will it be taller to have better vision and induce psychological effects on humans?
2. Will there be any changes in anatomy? For example, pillar feet vs angle feet. Or how many fingers does a soldier really need? Or maybe there are even more practical choices for limbs? The head is optional of course since we can put important parts in the torso, but I think that the head will still be there on future robot soldiers, just to look more humane, like a cosmetic thing. I am also pretty sure that some robots will be like dogs with guns mounted on back
3. The armor is what I find the most interesting. Will a future robot soldier be heavily armored to reduce the risk of losing this probably not-so-cheap robot from the first bullet hit? Or will such robots be considered disposable and used for some kind of zerg warfare, like droids in Star Wars, having very little armor? Or will there be both types?
4. Speaking about armor, how would it look like? This one keeps me from sleeping at night. As far as I know, modern tank armor utilizes a lot of angles to make it stronger, while an infantry vest is just a piece of kevlar/metal/ceramic which one wears on torso. Will a future robot soldier be armored like a tank with lots of angles and zero open joints like on medieval knight armor? Or will it be just some extra plates here and there like on modern military?

Let’s say we are talking about near future, literally USA/China/Russia in 10 years. Let’s also assume that the AI is advanced enough to be on par with average human soldier and the credibility of such robots is not questionable since drones are already here

Comment: "Since drones are already here" is not at all a blanket statement of credibility.  Drones are barely autonomous, and have the notable advantage of having no obstacles and being literally vehicles with standard power sources.  We're not going to see robotic soldiers in 10 years that don't look like APCs.

Comment: Please remember that we expect you to limit yourself to one question per post. We also expect questions to be specific, answerable and to not result in *many* valid answers. As a general rule brainstorming and idea generation aren't a good fit for this site.

Comment: Hello Vsevolod, welcome to worldbuilding. Please take a moment to take our [tour] and read the first two bullets in our [help] to better understand our site. Here at Stack Exchange, you're expected to ask just one question about a specific problem you're having with your worldbuilding project. Here, you've asked multiple questions and you're basically inviting a discussion, which is off-topic. Do you have one, specific problem you need help solving?  BTW, from an engineer's perspective, a "robot soldier" is called a "drone" be it in the shape of an airplane or a tank. See the issue?

Comment: Think about battle tanks: The first battle tanks were only lightly armored, and they were armed with small-caliber, anti-personnel weapons. But then the enemy caught on and started building their own tanks. As the design evolved, the primary mission of battle tanks became more and more specialized until it got to where their only real purpose on the battlefield was to fight the enemy's tanks. The evolution of autonomous weapons will be the same: Eventually their primary purpose will be to fight the enemy's autonomous weapons—whatever _that_ looks like!!

Answer (score 3):

**They will be nonthreatening and vaguely humanoid.**

[image: robot cop]

https://cdn.trendhunterstatic.com/thumbs/robot-cop.jpeg

One can do much better than a "soldier" when it comes to making war machines.    War machines look in no way like humans.  Drones and tanks would not be called soldiers.

Actual robot soldiers will be robots that represent an armed force and interface with human noncombatants.  This might be in occupied areas or in areas controlled by friendly forces that are used by the military.  Robot soldiers will interface with the people who live in these areas, serving as crowd control, police, and a representation of authority of the military force using the area.  In this role they need to look sort of like human police / soldiers but cannot be scary or creepy.

Answer (score 1):

I made a comment, but this seems relevant:

## They'll Look Like Armoured Vehicles

Humanoid robots are a terrible design.  The only reason you make humanoid robots is to fit into spaces designed for humans.  If you're making a robotic soldier, it's going to be an autonomous, armed APC, with the ability to deploy short-range armed/flying drones akin to the ones in [Slaughterbots](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9CO6M2HsoIA).

It will probably have a variable suspension and four to six wheel/bogeys, but there are very few missions where soldiers aren't travelling with vehicles anyway, so most places you can deploy soldiers you could deploy the Autonomous Armoured Reconnaissance and Deployment Vehicle: Advanced Role Kit, or AARDVARK.

Answer (score 1):

Robotic war machines will not be humanoid. And there won't be only one format but many.

One potentially highly effective format is the swarm.

[image]

This is a drone swarm. They coordinate with eachother and perform complicated aerial maneuvers. So far these have been mostly for artistic,  play, and celebration purposes.

Imagine 500 hundred of these things, talking to eachother by infared or radio, each carrying 10kg of high explosives. All doing complicated avoidance moves, flying at shirt-pocket height above the ground, using eachother's cameras to map the terrain, borrowing eachother's CPU power to estimate threats. If you manage to get a few, the rest swarm at you and give you a steady supply of 10kg bomb taps until you stop annoying them.

This kind of tech is certainly possibly today. A bit farther away is self-replicating devices.

[image]

This is a replicator from the TV show Stargate. It's actually a bunch of them. You can see that it is constructed of a large number of small blocks. You can see individual blocks at the end of the legs. The blocks interact at the surfaces to provide movement and cohesion.

[image]

They are called replicators because they can make more blocks from raw material they find. In Stargate, requiring special materials to do this was one of the few things that kept replicators from turning just about all matter into replicators.

By constructing different sized blocks with some degree of specialization, and by arranging them in different patterns, the replicators could produce many configurations with different powers. This went all the way from this spider-looking thing up to an entire planet's surface covered many meters deep.

Each one has a middle-level sophisticated CPU, some sensors, a supply of some chemicals. They can change configuration rapidly when some new obstacle appears. They can reform if they are shattered form whichever blocks are not damaged.  If you damage some of them the rest swarm at you and start doing things like spraying you with acid.

And each block is another cpu in a giant super computer. The more there are the smarter they get.